# angularjs: scope issue in directive when using $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having an issue with scope lost when using $compile to create a dynamic template for my directive. See the code below (trimmed for clarity) :

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('cdt.dm.directives').directive('serviceSources', ['$http', '$templateCache', '$compile', '$parse',
function ($http, $templateCache, $compile, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            type: '=',
            sources: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var template = 'Template_' + scope.type + '.html';

            $http.get(template, { cache: $templateCache }).success(function (tplContent) {
                element.replaceWith($compile(tplContent)(scope));
            });

            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
}
])
})();
```

that works and the html template is loaded.

the html template looks like:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>File</th>           
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-ng-reapeat="src in sources">
    <tr>
        <td>{{src.fileName}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

sources is an array with two elements. In the scope of the directive, it is definitely correct, but in the template, the ng-repeat is not working (I guess because sources is undefined at this stage).

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I wonder if you could just use `templateUrl` instead?

Comment: No, the template needs to be dynamic, based on the value passed to the 'type' variable on the scope. So I cannot use templateUrl.

Comment: I've edited the original code as per your recommendation, thanks.

Comment: Just to check, it's not the typo in ng-repeat is it?

Comment: sorry, forgot to tell you to wrap the code inside `scope.$apply`. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a typo: `ng-repeat` instead of `data-ng-reapeat`, and `ng-repeat` should be placed on `<tr>`

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>File</th>           
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="src in sources">
        <td>{{src.fileName}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Note that `$http.get` is asyn and remember to wrap the code inside `scope.$apply`. You should modify your code like this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var template = 'Template_' + scope.type + '.html';

            $http.get(template, { cache: $templateCache }).success(function (tplContent) {
              scope.$apply(function(){ 
                element.replaceWith(tplContent);
                $compile(element)(scope);
                //Or
                //element.html(tplContent);
                //$compile(element.contents())(scope);
               });
            });
        }
```

Comment: ng-repeat and data-ng-repeat are interchangeable. Same goes for all directives, they can all have data prefixed to them, even custom made directives.

Comment: @francisco.preller: if you look closely, you will see `reapeat` instead of `repeat`

Comment: Oh yeah, you're absolutely right. Thought you meant the latter. My bad :)

Comment: @francisco.preller: I meant both actually. In the question, I see:   `the ng-repeat is not working (I guess because sources is undefined at this stage)` . I thought the OP was referring to `ng-repeat` and I also did not know about `data-ng-repeat`, though. (I usually use `ng-repeat` this way). Thanks for pointing out `data-ng-repeat`

Comment: Sometimes instead of working late on a Friday evening and posting dumb questions on SO I should just enjoy the weekend.... :) Thanks a lot people for spotting the typo, that was just it... And also thanks for the great insights regarding $http.get, I wasn't finished with that and I'm going to improve it now based on your comment @Khanh TO.